# Unity2d Animation won't loop

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

Using unity 4.3.4f1.

I started a new project with only one game object on wich I added an animation with 4 sprites.  I choosed "Always Animate" from the Animator configuration oon the game object.

When I run the game, the animation play just one time.  I see in the animator panel that my animation is replayed again and again because I only have one state.  However, Animation won't loop when running the game.

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: Works fine for me when I do it... try clicking on the animation and make sure the "Loop" is ticked?

Comment: You were right, I noobed on this :)  Thank you :)